# How can you define multiple isAuthenticated functions in Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am building an app using Express/Node.js with Passport.js(passport-local) & Mongoose.

There are two kind of users:

1. regular users (they login using `/user-login` page and passport strategy `'local-user-login'`; regular users are stored in "Users" MongoDB collection)
2. admins (they login using `/admin-login` page and passport strategy `'local-admin-login'`; admins are stored in "Admins" MongoDB collection)

I also have 2 pages: `/user_home` (needs to be accessible to *logged regular users only*) and `/admin_home` (for *logged admins only*)

Route for `/user_home`:

```
app.get('/user_home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    // render the page
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

If I log in as an admin and try to access `/user_home`, it doesn't allow me, which is fine. My question is: **how can I define another "`isLoggedIn`" function that checks if I am logged in as an admin rather than a regular user?** Ideally I would like to have a function "isLoggedInAsUser" and another one "isLoggedInAsAdmin".

So far I tried defining the `/admin_home`  route the same way:

```
app.get('/admin_home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    // render the page
});
```

But it's obvious why it doesn't work. The code doesn't know that I want it to check if it's an admin rather than a regular user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passport stores authenticated user in `req.user`. So you can write middleware functions like this:

```
function allowAdmins(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user.role === 'Admin') return next();
  res.redirect('/user-login');
}

function allowRegular(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user.role === 'Regular') return next();
  res.redirect('/admin-login');
}
```

And then in routes:

```
var userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.use(isLoggedIn);
// Only authenticated users are allowed
userRouter.get('/home', isRegular, function (req, res) {});
userRouter.get('/admin', isAdmin, function (req, res) {});

app.use('/user', userRouter);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer, please? I am stuck in this. I want to implement isAuthenticated() for admin and I am not sure how to make the node get the Admin collectioin from Mongo.

Comment: @PrashanthVG Hi, for MongoDB access check the documentation. I would think that you will need to query the db in the middleware and after you validated it you can continue the execution by calling `next` callback.

Comment: Can you tell me how would you write isAuthenticated() for admin for the above case?

Answer (score 1):

in session object store role information

in the route configuration level, write middleware like

```
    var adminRoutes = express.routes();

    adminRoutes.route('/admin/*', function (req, res,next)
    {

    if(req.session.role==='Admin')

    return next();

   else
   {
   res.send("Authorization Error")
   }


    }
    app.use(adminRoutes);
```

same for user routes